# MVC with ASP.NET using Ajax 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have integrated code of my asp.net application with MVC appilcation.
I did integration by following that steps.

- Create new mvc application.
- Copy the code of asp.net application into that MVC application.

---

Some of my pages using Ajax 3.5 did not working. Like i have used HoverMenuexternder and modalpopupExtender of ajax 3.5 but it will not work after integration.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the AjaxControlToolkit. That only works in WebForms. 
In MVC you'll have to wire up the jQuery effects manually (or perhaps use another code framework, not sure if they exist for MVC)

Comment: I am using it on WebForms and these forms are integrated with MVC.